# Using verbose labels in query

Tags: sql, mysql, mariadb

I got some issues using "textual" aliases (= human readable, with spaces for instance) in sql queries.

For instance:
This query works perfectly:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN PROGRAM_TYPE Is NULL
    THEN ""
    ELSE PROGRAM_TYPE 
END AS NEW_FIELD
FROM T_PROGRAMS
GROUP By NEW_FIELD;
```

This one doesn't and return only one value of the precedent list:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN PROGRAM_TYPE Is NULL
    THEN ""
    ELSE PROGRAM_TYPE 
END AS "Program Type"
FROM T_PROGRAMS
GROUP By "Program Type";
```

Is there a way to use this kind of "verbose" aliases?

Comment: Use ` insted of " in the aliases, example END AS `Program Type`

Comment: When you put `GROUP BY "Program Type"` it means group by the literal string.  Use backticks to specify an identifier.  (Also, you might want to look at the `IFNULL` function)

Comment: @RobEyre Great comment.  You could answer, and mention that MySQL has the quirk of allowing double quotes for string literals.

Comment: MySQL allows using ordinal positions with `GROUP BY`.  So `GROUP BY 1` would also work with your query.

Comment: Or one could use the sql_mode to make MySQL use double-quotes as identifier delimiters, as most other SQL implementations do.

Comment: Thanks all of you. I've tried with ' instead of " with no success but @PauloACoelho answer solve it.

Comment: I like @TimBiegeleisen answer too! Great one.